# JiBX framework jars not in classpath

Tags: java, xml, soap, maven, apache-axis

I have a maven project with Axis2 and I'm trying to use JiBX as codegen-engine.
Running wsdl2code -d jibx works, but integrating it with maven build process isn't working.
I've searched for it but all the results I've found didn't have any replies.
What can I do to remedy this error?
I thought maven would handle the dependencies.

Maven output:

```
[INFO] [axis2-wsdl2code:wsdl2code {execution: EchoWS}]
Retrieving document at 'http://localhost:8080/EchoWS/EchoWS?wsdl'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.JiBXExtension.engage(JiBXExtension.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:246)
        at org.apache.axis2.maven2.wsdl2code.WSDL2CodeMojo.execute(WSDL2CodeMojo.java:567)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath
        at org.apache.axis2.maven2.wsdl2code.WSDL2CodeMojo.execute(WSDL2CodeMojo.java:574)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
        at org.apache.axis2.maven2.wsdl2code.WSDL2CodeMojo.execute(WSDL2CodeMojo.java:567)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JiBX framework jars not in classpath
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.JiBXExtension.engage(JiBXExtension.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:246)
        ... 20 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 31 18:06:17 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <!-- $Id$ -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.dkon.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>omais-ws</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>${omais-dkon-version}</version>
    <name>omais WS</name>
    <description>
        The omais application webservices.
    </description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.dkon</groupId>
        <artifactId>omais-parent</artifactId>
        <version>DKON-1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <pmdRuleSetDir>..</pmdRuleSetDir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossws-jboss50</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jibx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EchoWS</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>com.example.dkon.application</packageName>
                            <wsdlFile>http://localhost:8080/omais/EchoWS/EchoWS?wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <unwrap>true</unwrap>
                            <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                            <databindingName>jibx</databindingName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentFacadeWS</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>com.example.dkon.dkon.application</packageName>
                            <wsdlFile>http://localhost:8080/omais/DocumentFacadeWS/DocumentFacadeWS?wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <unwrap>true</unwrap>
                            <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                            <databindingName>jibx</databindingName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the JiBX dependencies to the plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
  </plugin>
```